# What is the difference between `Class` and `class`

Tags: ruby

While creating a class, we use the keyword `class` like:

```
class Abc
  Z = 5
  def add
    puts "anything here"
  end
end
```

In console, `Abc.class # => Class`

How does `Abc` internally become a class? What is the difference between `class` and `Class`?

It would be great if anyone could explain how class constants and method are internally called, and if a method is not defined, then how we get the exception `"undefined class method"`. What is the internal logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what the different *"class"* things in Ruby mean, check out [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32601329/2423164).

---

As for how methods are looked up:

There are multiple places a method can come from:

1. The class of the object
2. The parent of the class of the object
3. Modules, which are included/prepended
4. The singleton class of the object

The order of lookup is the following:

1. If it exists, the singleton class
2. Prepended modules
3. Methods defined in the class
4. Included modules
5. Recursively, the above rules for the parent class

There are a few things that have to be noted here:

1. If multiple modules are included/prepended, they will be looked up in the reverse order of how they were included/prepended
2. If a module was already included/prepended in one of the parrents, it won't be included/prepended again
3. If using these rules the method was not found til the very start of the hierarchy (`BasicObject`), the ancestor chain is searched again for a different method, called `method_missing`
4. `BasicObject#method_missing` is defined so that it throws a `NoMethodError` and that is where the error comes from

---

```
module M1
  def foo
    puts 'Defined in M1'
  end
end

module M2
  def foo
    puts 'Defined in M2'
  end
end

class C
  include M1
  prepend M2

  def foo
    puts 'Defined in C'
  end

  def method_missing(method_name)
    puts 'Method missing' if method_name == :foo
  end
end

c = C.new

# singleton method
def c.foo
  puts "Defined in c's singleton"
end

puts c.singleton_class.ancestors
  # => [#<Class:#<C:0xa2d0f8>>, M2, C, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
  #     ^ the singleton class,
  #       the prepended module,
  #       the C class itself,
  #       the included module,
  #       the rest of the hierarchy
  # (Object is the implicit parent of all classes with no explicit parent)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your lovely explanation.

Answer (score 14):

There are three different things here:

1. `class` is a keyword, which is used to define or reopen a class
2. [`Object#class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-class) is a method, which returns the class of a given object
3. [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html) is the class which all classes are an instance of (including `Class` itself)

Comment: You explanation is really appreciated but it would be nice if you could explain me the internal working from creating a class to calling its method.

Comment: @Chitra, do you mean how `bar` will be found when you invoke `foo.bar` ? Or how Ruby stores classes?

Comment: Yes, and one more question is here like if we call a method with class's instance and that method is not declare within the class, from where we got this exception "NoMethodError: " how it is called and is there any way to override the existing class method and create a run time custom method. so that we can'not get this exception "NoMethodError:" method again.

Comment: @Chitra, where `NoMethodError` originates from is the place you called it, are you asking how to get the stack trace? On a low level, it is probably complex, I would suggest you search places where the [`NoMethodError` is being created](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/f94ed2ce4bcf201a4d16a85f0fdbbfce4ea20e35/error.c#L1108). About how to define a method if it's missing - you can reopen the class or define a singleton class and define the method there. Also, if you are searching for a way to never throw `NoMethodError` no matter what method you call, you can use `BasicObject#method_missing`.

Comment: @Chitra, I created another answer, I hope it answers your remaining questions.

Answer (score 2):

[ndn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32601329/477037) gives a nice overview of the different things "class" could refer to.

To answer your specific question:

> How does `Abc` internally become a class?

Almost like any other object.

```
class Abc
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
Abc = Class.new do
end
```

It creates a new instance of `Class` and assigns it to the constant `Abc`.

Answer (score 1):

with `class Abc` you define a class.

`Abc.class` is returning the Type, and the type of Abc is a `Class`

another example:

```
1337.class
=> Fixnum
"hi babe!".class
=> String
12.55.class
=> Float
(1..12).class
=> Range
```

so as you can see, each "datatype" is a class. in your case `Abc` is also a Datatype. And for the end of that chain, the class of a class is Class! :-)

Comment: `#class` returns object's class, there is no clear concept of 'type' in Ruby.

Comment: i just used the word "type / datatype" since you have all kind of datatypes in other languages, where those are datatypes while these are classes in ruby

Comment: Point is, Ruby is "duck-typed", and so closest equivalent of object's 'type' is it's singleton class, or method set, neither of which is returned by `#class`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering second par of the question, `undefined class method` happens when method you called is not present in such class - classes are just objects in Ruby, and as such they have their own set of methods. Ruby has several ways to define class methods, most common is probably

```
class Klass
  def self.klass_method
    ...
  end
end
```

the other is

```
class Klass
  #  some ordinary instance methods here
  class << self
    def klass_method
      # this is class method
    end
  end
end
```

Some Rubyists prefer the latter, as it keeps all class methods in single block, but they are equivalent.